# Multiple actions for single trigger

Tags: if-this-then-that

I am intending to make a quick tool to find my phone when I lose it. The way I currently have it set up is:

`If I tell Google Home "Find my Phone"` then `call my phone`

`If I tell Google Home "Turn my ringer up"` then `set my phone ringer up (Using the Android phone channel)`

But I want to combine them both into the "Find my phone" applet/recipe. Basically, I want one applet/recipe to have two actions. It is not feasible to have two of the same triggers, because these triggers are for the Google Home. I know this is possible because many published recipes have this.

Can you please show me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Davi](https://www.daviraimundo.com/how-to-execute-multiple-actions-with-ifttt/) offers three choices, of which the one recommended is:

> In order to get the actions to happen in the right order, we need to delay the phone call just long enough for the volume to be set. If we combine Option 1 and 2, we are able to create that delay.
>
> As with option 2, we will have 3 applets.
>
> ```
> Applet 1:
>     Trigger: Google Assistant – Phrase: find my phone
>     Action: Android Device - Set ringtone volume to 100%
> Applet 2:
>     Trigger: Google Assistant – Phrase: find my phone
>     Action: Maker – Make web request: find_my_phone
> Applet 3:
>     Trigger: Maker – Receive web request: find_my_phone
>     Action: Phone Call
> ```
>
> As you can see, Applet 1 and 2 are similar to Option 1 being triggered
>   by the initial input in the Assistant. But, instead of making the call
>   on Applet 2, we add a step of calling out to Maker, and triggering
>   another applet, which, in turn, makes the phone call. That additional
>   hop creates the delay necessary for all of it to happen in the right
>   order.